# Adding a command into a specific cog

Tags: discord.py

I want to add the command into a specific cog called `features.py` with the cog name `Features`, but I'm lost on how to use the `cog` attribute.

```py
bot.command(name='add-prefix',aliases=['add-bot-prefix','bot-prefix'],cog="HOW TO I ADD IT TO Features?")
async def add_prefix(msg,prefix):
   pass
   #my code here
```

My cog in a separate file

```py
class Features(commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self,client):
       self.bot=client

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Features(bot))
```

Comment: Do you already have a `Features` cog?  Usually commands are part of a cog because the cog class is defined with the command: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html

Comment: Yes, I have a separate file that has the cog `Features`

Comment: What's the purpose of adding the command outside of the cog instead of in the cog definition?

Comment: I have a command that lets users add custom command prefix in the main file because I have it connected to a database and the only way to update it is from the same file. I'm using pymongodb.